# Get print layout's item width and height in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to create a function that will return the `width` and `height` of a print layout item.

This one doesn't work.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
@qgsfunction(args= 'auto' , group='Custom')
def GetItemWidth (LayoutName , ItemName, feature, parent):
    #variables
    layout_name = LayoutName
    item_name = ItemName

    #getting the layout
    manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
    layout = manager.layoutByName(layout_name)

    item = layout.itemById(item_name)
    item_width = item.ItemWidth()
   
    return item_width
```

I guess the problem come from :

```
item = layout.itemById(item_name)
item_width = item.ItemWidth()
```

Any idea? I'm interested for to create another function to return `height`.

Comment: Maybe to search around the QgsLayoutItem method `item.rectWithFrame()` (doc: https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItem.html#a4e93d602fb3b8f40402badce4bff6534) to get a QRectF (doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html) and get the width `item.rectWithFrame().width()` and height `item.rectWithFrame().height()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `sizeWithUnits` first.

```
item = layout.itemById(item_name)
item_size = item.sizeWithUnits()
item_height = item_size.height()

# for width
# item_width = item_size.width()
```